# Using Transform.position with collider

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So i have my movement written with transform.position, i dont wanna use a rigidbody since im using my own physics calculations. which in return for me just would introduce extra steps (which i dont even need, since im essentially nulling everything out, plus it would introduce new bugs (for example in my slope movement)... so, i need something that limits my possible movement directions, limited by the hitlocations of my collider, i was thinking about raycasts, which would work... but i have to shoot way too many raycasts, and is not foolproof by any means even if it were 8 directional raycasts... anyone any ideas or a solution to my problem?

Code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Movement : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Player")]
    public float PlayerHeight = 2f;

    [Header("Objects")]
    public Transform Direction;

    // Input
    float CurrentMoveX;
    float CurrentMoveZ;

    float TargetMoveX;
    float TargetMoveZ;

    [Header("Settings")]
    public float CurrentMoveSpeedMode = 5f;

    [Header("Movement Physics")]
    public float AccelSpeed = 4.5f;
    public float DeaccelSpeed = 4.5f;
    public float SnapRange = 0.01f;

    [Header("Gravity Physics")]
    public float GravityStrength = 1f;

    [Header("Ground")]
    public float GroundDetectionRadius = 0.3f;
    bool IsGrounded;

    // Units
    float GForce = 9.80665f;
    float SpeedConversionValue = 3.6f;

    // Direction
    Vector3 MoveDirection;

    // Vertical
    float CurrentVerticalVelocity;

    void Update()
    {
        HorizontalMovement();
        MoveOutput(); 
    }
    void HorizontalMovement()
    { 
         InputDirection();
         EditedDirection();
         Ground();
    }
    void InputDirection()
    { 
        // Move X - Horizontal
        if(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") < 0f)
        { 
            TargetMoveX = -CurrentMoveSpeedMode / SpeedConversionValue;

            if(CurrentMoveX > TargetMoveX)
            { 
                if(CurrentMoveX > 0f)
                { 
                    CurrentMoveX -= GForce * (AccelSpeed + DeaccelSpeed) * Time.deltaTime;
                }
                else if(CurrentMoveX <= 0f)
                { 
                    CurrentMoveX -= GForce * AccelSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
                }           
            }
            else if(CurrentMoveX <= TargetMoveX)
            {
                CurrentMoveX = TargetMoveX;
            }
        }
        else if(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") > 0f)
        { 
            TargetMoveX = CurrentMoveSpeedMode / SpeedConversionValue;

            if(CurrentMoveX < TargetMoveX)
            { 
                if(CurrentMoveX < 0f)
                { 
                    CurrentMoveX += GForce * (AccelSpeed + DeaccelSpeed) * Time.deltaTime;
                }
                else if(CurrentMoveX >= 0f)
                { 
                    CurrentMoveX += GForce * AccelSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
                }                
            }
            else if(CurrentMoveX >= TargetMoveX)
            {
                CurrentMoveX = TargetMoveX;
            }
        }
        else if(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") == 0f)
        { 
            TargetMoveX = 0f;

            if(CurrentMoveX > 0.1f)
            { 
                CurrentMoveX -= GForce * (AccelSpeed + DeaccelSpeed) * Time.deltaTime;
            }
            else if(CurrentMoveX < -0.1f)
            { 
                CurrentMoveX += GForce * AccelSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
            }
            else
            { 
                CurrentMoveX = TargetMoveX;
            }
        }

        // Move Z - Vertical
        if(Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical") < 0f)
        { 
            TargetMoveZ = -CurrentMoveSpeedMode / SpeedConversionValue;

            if(CurrentMoveZ > TargetMoveZ)
            { 
                if(CurrentMoveZ > 0f)
                { 
                    CurrentMoveZ -= GForce * (AccelSpeed + DeaccelSpeed) * Time.deltaTime;
                }
                else if(CurrentMoveZ <= 0f)
                { 
                    CurrentMoveZ -= GForce * AccelSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
                }           
            }
            else if(CurrentMoveZ <= TargetMoveZ)
            {
                CurrentMoveZ = TargetMoveZ;
            }
        }
        else if(Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical") > 0f)
        { 
            TargetMoveZ = CurrentMoveSpeedMode / SpeedConversionValue;

            if(CurrentMoveZ < TargetMoveZ)
            { 
                if(CurrentMoveZ < 0f)
                { 
                    CurrentMoveZ += GForce * (AccelSpeed + DeaccelSpeed) * Time.deltaTime;
                }
                else if(CurrentMoveZ >= 0f)
                { 
                    CurrentMoveZ += GForce * AccelSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
                }                
            }
            else if(CurrentMoveZ >= TargetMoveZ)
            {
                CurrentMoveZ = TargetMoveZ;
            }
        }
        else if(Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical") == 0f)
        { 
            TargetMoveZ = 0f;

            if(CurrentMoveZ > SnapRange)
            { 
                CurrentMoveZ -= GForce * (AccelSpeed + DeaccelSpeed) * Time.deltaTime;
            }
            else if(CurrentMoveZ < -SnapRange)
            { 
                CurrentMoveZ += GForce * AccelSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
            }
            else
            { 
                CurrentMoveZ = TargetMoveZ;
            }
        }
    }
    void EditedDirection()
    { 
        // Directionalize And Normalize Movement Input
        Vector3 DirectionInput = Direction.forward * CurrentMoveZ + Direction.right * CurrentMoveX;
        Vector3 DirectionNormal = DirectionInput.normalized;
                DirectionNormal = new Vector3(Mathf.Abs(DirectionNormal.x), 0, Mathf.Abs(DirectionNormal.z));
        Vector3 OutputDirection = new Vector3(DirectionInput.x * DirectionNormal.x, 0, DirectionInput.z * DirectionNormal.z);


        // Slope Detection
        RaycastHit TerrainHit;

        if(Physics.SphereCast(transform.position, PlayerHeight / 4f, Vector3.down, out TerrainHit))
        {
            if(TerrainHit.normal != Vector3.up)
            { 
                OnSlopeFunction();     
            }
            else
            { 
                NotOnSlopeFunction();
            }
        }
        else
        { 
            NotOnSlopeFunction();
        }

        // Follow Terrain/Slopes

        void OnSlopeFunction()
        { 
            MoveDirection = Vector3.ProjectOnPlane(OutputDirection, TerrainHit.normal);             
        }
        void NotOnSlopeFunction()
        { 
            MoveDirection = OutputDirection;
        }
    }
    void Ground()
    { 
        // Prevent Clipping Through Floor (Especially when moving down slopes)

        GroundAlign();            

        void GroundAlign()
        {
            RaycastHit GroundAlignHit;
            
            if(Physics.Raycast(transform.position, Vector3.down, out GroundAlignHit, PlayerHeight / 2f))
            { 
                Vector3 GroundAlignPos = GroundAlignHit.point;
                transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, GroundAlignPos.y + PlayerHeight / 2f, transform.position.z);
            }
        }
    }

    void MoveOutput()
    { 
        // Output Movement
        transform.position = MoveDirection * Time.deltaTime;
    }
}
```

Rigidbody, expected to movement to function normally, seems to not be the result, transform.position also seems to be smoother since it doesnt need to calculate physics, its based on custom physics values, stored in floats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without looking too much into it I would cut in at your `MoveOutput` function. Assuming your collider is just a primitive you could check for "Overlaps" using [`Physics.OverlapCapsule`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.OverlapCapsule.html) (cube and sphere also available) before you apply the new position.

```csharp
void MoveOutput()
{
    Vector3 newPos = transform.position + MoveDirection * Time.deltaTime;
    //TODO adjust parameters to your needs
    //NOTE the capsule is always upright no matter how your object is rotated
    float height = 2;
    if(Physics.OverlapCapsule(newPos - (height / 2) * Vector3.up, newPos + (height / 2) * Vector3.up, 0.5f).Length == 0)
    {
        transform.position = newPos;
    }
}
```

The code will prevent you from entering a wall. You will **not** slide along if you go in at an angle.

Please note that framerate drops can cause some jank that can get you out of bounds or stuck. I would urge you to switch your `Update` with a `FixedUpdate` for more consistency.

Comment: yeah, i know. the script is not finished yet. still gotta seperate update and fixedupdate... but functionality wise... it makes practically zero difference. but thanks! gonna try, exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: i actually need the defention for overlapcapslue, but it requires 2 vectors? not one? also .length seems to not be a defenition. if i try without it cant convert it to a boolian. without the if parameters, it essentially does nothing.

Comment: You haven't read the documentation too closely, did you? The two vectors describe the start and end points of a path that a sphere with the radius slides along, carving out a cylinder. I have adjusted my answer so that it checks for the same shape as a default capsule. I'd like to apologize in regards of the missing `length` property, your compiler is correct it should be `Length` I forgot to capitalize when writing.

Comment: i have read it, but the documentation can sometimes be kinda unclear in how they explain things... or my brain just didnt function yesterday... either way... thanks for getting back to me. gonna try it again.

Comment: https://youtu.be/fa7VBJFir3U seems to be the result...

Comment: i seem to be getting some understanding of what your are doing, you make a collider in my next to be position and check if it collides with a collider, if it doesnt. you can move, i think its smart... only the bool seems to not come back with anything...

Comment: nvm, figured out the problem... collider was hitting the ground... thanks dude. works flawlessly!!!

Comment: Don't forget to mark as solved then!